# Why does JSONPath not support parent?

Tags: jsonpath

[JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) seems to be a popular syntax to get XPath-like searching inside JSON data. And it has been repeatedly asked *whether* JSONPath supports navigation to a parent (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31226500/2420536) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16909739/2420536)).

My question is whether there is a good reason *why* it has not been suggested from the start, even though it is explicitly mentioned as unsupported. Is there some syntactic reason from JavaScript? Or is there some general workaround that I am missing?

Comment: Hoping this does not count as "too broad" or "unclear"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specification was written up on a blog; AFAIK, it is not part of any ongoing committee standardization.

However, to meet the need for parent accessors (and other features), at least one implementation, [JSONPath-plus](https://github.com/s3u/JSONPath/) which is a superset of the original spec, allows for accessing parents through a number of means (see the README docs).

Disclaimer: I am involved in working on this implementation.