# how to use jsonpath in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, jsonpath

Is there a way to use jsonpath in mongodb 3.4/3.6? Sample  is shown below , as in reference link [JSON path parent object, or equivalent MongoDB query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909739/json-path-parent-object-or-equivalent-mongodb-query) :

```
 var t1 = db.runCommand({aggregate : 'news_feeds',
pipeline:[],

cursor : {batchSize : 10}});
     t1.cursor.firstBatch.forEach(function(doc)
   {
var json = tojson(doc);
var json1="$.feeds.reviews[*].name"
var result = jsonPath(json, json1);
print(result);
  })
```

This query gives an error that jsonPath is not defined, but this jsonpath is there in the javascript

Please help

regards

kris

Comment: That error is because MongoDB shell doesn't recognize `jsonPath` as a function. MongoDB does not currently support jsonPath.

Comment: is there a alternate way to use jsonpath in mongodb?

Comment: Even I installed json-path using npm,  and tried to execute,it says require is not defined, please help var jpath = require('json-path');

var t1 = db.runCommand({aggregate : 'news_feeds',
pipeline:[],

cursor : {batchSize : 10}});
     t1.cursor.firstBatch.forEach(function(doc)
   {
var json = tojson(doc);
    var res = jpath.resolve(json, "$.feeds.reviews[*].name")
print(res);
  })

Comment: `npm` and MongoDB shell are two different things. `npm` is for node. The only similarity between the two is that both uses Javascript as a language. I'm not familiar with how jsonPath was implemented, but there _may_ be a method to execute the jsonPath package inside the `mongo` shell, but MongoDB itself never support the use of jsonPath.

Answer (score 3):

Solved by using mongodb-shell-extensions https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-shell-extensions#jsonpath works pretty well.

Regards
Kris

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wanted to update a field in Mongo DB and I had the JSON path for the field. I ended up using some simple string replace to do the conversion from JSON path to mongo query path.

```
private String toMongoPath(@Nonnull String jsonPath) {
    return jsonPath.replace("'", "")
            .replace("][", ".")
            .replace("$[", "")
            .replace("]", "");
}
```

Input:

```
$['store']['book'][0]['title']
```

Output:

```
store.book.0.title
```